# Someone shared an EC2 instance with me, but it has the SSH keys from the other account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I got an AMI shared with me that is basically an instance copy from a EC2 related to a different account. It is a server with an EBS volume attached to it. I created an EC2 instance from that AMI. So far so good.

However, I can only access it using the SSH pem file from the other account. But obviously I want to access it with the SSH pair from my current account.

How do I do that? I would have expected to be able to access the instance with the SSH from my new account.

Comment: How did you create the instance?  During creation is should ask you for a key.  Which key did you give it?

Comment: I use Launch Instance => My AMIs => Shared with me.
I don't see any such option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ssh keys are independent from AWS and there's no reason for them to update automatically. You have to edit the `authorized_keys` file located in your .ssh directory `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and add the public key of your desired key pair to that file.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. I also cleaned known_hosts and did a `sudo service ssh restart` but still no joy. I can still login with the "old" pem and not the new

Comment: If you've change the authorized keys on the remote machine you shouldn't be able to do that, are you sure you've edited on correct machine?